# Is this a viable method to secure user accounts?

Tags: php, authentication, cookies

I stumbled upon a method of securing user accounts which basically automates the user's password. From a user perspective I think it's much better than a conventional passwords and I think also from a security perspective it would be preferred over conventional passwords.

I'm developing a PHP based application that will be a companion app for a video game. Which is only relevant to explain the link I'm going to post for others to test the method I'm proposing. It involves multiple files so posting a link and asking people to try the method is the best "explanation" that I can provide but I will brief the method also.

The user provides an email address to create an account. The program generates an email with a link in it. When the user follows the link in their email, an access cookie is set on their device.

The user is given control over the cookies which grant access to their account. The user can revoke access cookies and set new access cookies on other devices.

The program also compares access cookies and fingerprints, and will revoke access cookies when the device's access cookie and fingerprint don't match with the database.

Revoking a cookie has two effects. The database connection between the device and the account is updated so the revoked cookie no longer provides access to any accounts, and the revoked cookie is subsequently unset from any devices it's found on.

Included is a picture of the user account page which shows the Access List, the list of cookies that currently grant access to this user account. The user can revoke access from this page or send another email to set a cookie on another device. The image demonstrates an account which has two access cookies granting access to the account from two devices.

The user or program can revoke all access cookies and still the user can send an email to the address associated with their account and easily regain access to their account.

Depending on the device fingerprinting method, the user will need to reset cookies on devices after browser updates or changing plugins.

On the positive, they don't need another password. Passwords are commonly referred to as the "weak" link in an account and this method essentially automates, refreshes and maintains the integrity of passwords through cookies and an associated email account. As I mentioned in the beginning, from the user perspective I think this experience was much better than a conventional password system. So now I want to learn how this method is vulnerable and how those vulnerabilities might be mitigated. I understand that this question is less concrete than what is expected for stackoverflow but if not here then where do I get this feedback? Links?

Obviously the actual code may be a security risk but I thought we could get to that level of detail later? If you're interested please try the implementation at the link. The site is themed after a video game so please be patient with the color scheme, only the account control feature is working right now. Navigate to the account page, enter a fake username and a real email address and then if you have multiple devices please try setting access cookies on them. I have verified the program working as intended on 2 Windows/Chrome devices and 1 Android device. None of your information will be retained.

[development url](https://derekscottroberts.com/)

[image: Picture of user account page cookie Access List]

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether this is not "too opinion based" for stackoverflow. My 2 cents: I like the idea, but it includes the fact that the only thing that the user logs in with was sent over an unencrypted medium (which email usually is), and hence I think it is mighty vulnerable right there

Comment: @rickdenhaan Code Review requires actual code to review. This sort of design review is off-topic there.

Comment: @bruglesco good point, I've retracted my close vote for that specific reason. Even so, I still feel this question should still be closed as off-topic here as well.

Comment: @rickdenhaan sure. Then vote to close for another reason. (too broad? POB?). But you should never vote to close something just because it fits elsewhere if it still fits here.

Comment: So what do you need, a github repository of the several files and database tables which are required to get this method working? It seemed unreasonable to try to include all that in a single post here

Comment: rickdenhaan thank you for the link I think I agree!